# ¿Cómo recuperar el id de un registro que recién hice en SQL?

Tags: sql, insert, identity

Necesito recuperar el id del registro que hago tan pronto inserto información. Es decir, quiero insertar un contrato y que me devulva el id del contrato insertado para poder darle el valor de este id a **@IdContrato** y hacer el insert en EstatusContrado

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer eso?

```
insert into Contratos
  (IdEmpresa, IdProyecto, IdCatTipoContrato, Nombre,
    TipoPersona, TieneArchivo, IdUsuarioOperacion, Activo, Fecha,
    IdCatEstatusContrato, FechaInicioVigencia, FechaFinVigencia,
    FechaFirma, Importe, esCliente, Folio, Consecutivo, Cliente, idProveedor)
values
  (@IdEmpresa, @idProyecto, @IdCatTipoContrato, @Nombre,
    @TipoPersona, 1, @idUsuario, 1, GETDATE(),
    @IdCatEstatusContrato, @FechaInicioVigencia, @FechaFinVigencia,
    @FechaFirma, @Importe, @EsCliente, @Folio, @Consecutivo, @Cliente, @IdProveedor)

set @IdContrato = --select ? supongo, algo que me devuelva el valor de IdContrato

insert into EstatusContrato
  (IdContrato, IdCatEstatusContrato, IdUsuarioOperacion, fecha, Activo)
values
  (@IdContrato, @IdCatEstatusContrato, @IdUsuarioOperacion, getdate(), 1)
```

Comment: Podrias aclarar de que db estas hablando?

Comment: Hola amigo, en SQL SERVER, lo puedes hacer tal como se explica en el siguiente enlace, suerte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert

Comment: Mil gracias, deseas postear un respuesta para que te la de? @waimaku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yo supongo que es SQL SERVER según veo tu código.
Personalmente suelo utilizar lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Adicionalmente te paso un enlace con mas ejemplos, suerte: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Después del **INSERT** selecciona el último **id** registrado de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS IdEmpresa
```

O también así:

```
INSERT INTO Contratos;

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```